# specified dsn contains architecture mismatch between application and driver

Tags: dsn, mismatch

I am using eclipse and apache tomcat 7.0.0 on windows8 64-bit. while connecting access database in my jsp application i always get the problem of architecture mismatch between application and driver, while in normal java application jdbc-odbc connection works properly. so i got latest version of apache tomcat 8.0.0 but eclipse doesn‘t have the server adapter for tomcat 8.0.0. so how to connect the access database with jsp application using eclipse? Please help me because i am doing my final year project in jsp.